# Как использовать SCSS внутри React без компиляции в CSS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scss

Привет я новичок в REACT, и я нуждаюсь использовать SCSS без компиляций т.е без лишних CSSфайлов. Есть ли в React такая особенность ? Заранее спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставишь npm зависимость через

```
$ npm install sass
# or
$ yarn add sass
```

После этого подключение scss файлов в проект, происходит как и обыскного css, просто указывая формат `@use 'styles/_colors.scss';` CSS появяться при компилировании проекта, а так React сам за тебя решит вопрос отслеживания.